# Load-time weaving with AspectJ

Tags: runtime, aop, aspectj, aspect, load-time-weaving

I need to add aspects on runtime in AspectJ. Right now I am using Spring AOP. It is not allowing me to add aspects without restarting the JVM.

The following is my aspect in Spring AOP. Now I need to add extra methods to my aspect during runtime.

```java
package com.pennant.aop;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableLoadTimeWeaving;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect

public class AOPAspect {
    
    @Pointcut("execution(* com.pennant.aop.Test.*(..))  ")
    public static boolean someCallWithIfTest() {
       return 3 > 0;
    }

    @Around("@annotation(com.pennant.aop.AroundAdvice)")
    public void logAroundAllMethods(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        String methodName = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
        String classname = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName();
        LogManager.getLogger(joinPoint.getTarget().getClass()).debug(Literal.ENTERING,classname+1, methodName);
        try {
            joinPoint.proceed();
        }
        finally {}
        LogManager.getLogger(joinPoint.getTarget().getClass()).debug(Literal.LEAVING,classname+1, methodName);
    }  
          
}
```

Comment: And the question is? What is the problem?

Comment: I added syntax highlighting, fixed your code formatting and the worst spelling and punctuation mistakes. But I agree with @IspasClaudiu that the most important things are missing: the actual question and the description of what you have tried and which problems occurred. You also did not explain why you seem to expect to be able to change aspects during runtime with AspectJ and what exactly you want to achieve. Please give your question some more love and edit it, ideally provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reproducing your problem. Thank you very much. :-)